# Reserving space for child windows similar to menu bar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sdl

I am writing a DLL to be injected into a process which creates a SDL game window. I am able to create child windows and listen in on messages, but one thing I am having a difficult time doing and finding out how to do is stealing space that won't be used in drawing the game frame.

What I mean is, I want to give space to my windows in the same way the menu bar has space. When I SetMenu, the rest of the window scrunches down into the remaining space automatically. However, for a window created with CreateWindowEx, I can find no way of doing something similar.

I know there are a lot of unknown and potentially important factors here that would decide the best course of action, but is there any win32 function I haven't found that could help with this? They don't have to change in size often much. I just would like something like:

```
ReserveSpace(wnd, 0, 0, width, 20);
// Place CreateWindowEx-ed HWND there
```

(well, I don't expect something so simple).

Is this easily possible? I know "reserving" a rectangle of any size doesn't make sense, I would have to reserve a row or column if it is possible, but that is fine and expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that you have to *"reserve"* anything? Just render your window in front of your target window. Making your window an owned window does all that automatically for you.

Comment: @IInspectable Could you elaborate? The window I'm adding stuff to isn't "mine" and I don't have the source.

Comment: [Owned Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

Comment: @IInspectable Ahh I see what you mean. It is a child window and it acts as a child window perfectly, but it overlays the "box" that takes up all of the window space in which the game is rendered. My goal is to chop off rows and columns from the sides like the behavior of the menu bar; I want it to have its own space and still have all of the rest of the window visible, just compressed into the remaining space. Unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry for the quality of this but perhaps this shows it? https://puu.sh/vls2t/d296c8f9f7.png I want to draw the left box and have the A not hidden at all, just smaller, without messing with it directly

Comment: If that's what you want you need to infiltrate the message processing of the game window, and handle the [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634.aspx) message. That may or may not work, depending on how the game determines the window's client size for it's viewport.

Comment: @IInspectable I had been hooking GetMessageW rather than replacing the WndProc so once I fixed that that works. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it and it's easier for others to find? Thanks!! It works perfectly. (Well, I reserved space, at least. I still need to figure out how to draw my window there)